# Continue iterating through an array at certain step beyond its boundaries

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I'm looking for a way to iterate through an array with a certain step ( >= 1) in a certain direction (left or right). If I get out of the boundaries of the array I should enter from the other side, keeping the step constant. For a graphic representation please refer to the example.
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about circular arrays, where where the index excedes the array size you start at the beginning again

```
  int[] arr = new arr[3]; 
  int i = 4;

    if (i > 0)
        int index  = (i % arr.Length) ;
```

and in a step iteration format

```
int step = 2;
for(int i=0; i < ? ; i+= step)
{
      int index  = (i % arr.Length) ; 
     // do something with index
}
```

Comment: you should add `arr.Length` for negative step. `index = (index + step + arr.Length) % arr.Length`